# Object.Values keys render all on one line instead of one line per item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Countries = ({searchedCountries}) => {
  console.log(searchedCountries.map(c => c.languages))
  if (searchedCountries.length >= 10) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>too many countries to list, please narrow your search</p>
      </div>
    )
  } 
  if (searchedCountries.length === 1) {
    return (
      <div>
capital: {searchedCountries.map(c => <p>{c.capital}</p>)}
area: {searchedCountries.map(c => <p>{c.area}</p>)}
<h2>Languages</h2>
<ul>
{searchedCountries.map(c => <li>{Object.values(c.languages)}</li>)}
</ul>
{searchedCountries.map(c => <img src={Object.values(c.flags)[0]} /> )}
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <ul>
    {searchedCountries.map(c => <li>{c.name.common}</li>)}
  </ul>
  )
}

const App = () => {
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
const [newSearch, setNewSearch] = useState('')

const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
  setNewSearch(event.target.value)
}

const searchedCountries = 
countries.filter(c => c.name.common.includes(newSearch))

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('effect')
  axios
  .get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
  .then(response => {
    console.log('promise fulfilled')
    setCountries(response.data)
  })
}, [])

  return (
    <div>
<div><p>find countries</p><input value={newSearch} onChange={handleSearchChange} /></div>
<div>
  <h2>countries</h2>
  <Countries searchedCountries={searchedCountries} />
</div>
    </div>
  )
}



export default App;
```

I am trying to list the languages of each country in my app, however, the languages render like this:

-EnglishSwedishItalian

instead of like this:

- English
- Swedish
- Italian

Does anyone know how to render each of the Object.values(c.lanaguages) on its own line instead of all bunched together on one line?

Thanks.

Comment: You're passing an array in a single `<li>` you'll need to `map()` the values array. `{searchedCountries.map(c => <ul>{Object.values(c.languages).map(l => <li>{l}</li>)}</ul>)}`

Comment: It would help if you could provide your `countries` array or an example from it

Comment: I didn't say `c.languages.map` I recommended `Object.values(c.languages).map`. `Object.values` returns an array so the only reason you would get an error is if there is inconsistency between `country.languages`. As @tgikf said, you'll need to post a sample of your data for more specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array (`Obect.values(c.languages)`) in a single `<li>` which gets flattened to a string by React.

```
<ul>
  {searchedCountries.map(c => <li>{Object.values(c.languages)}</li>)}
</ul>
```

You'll need to instead `map()` the values array.

```
<ul>
  {
    searchedCountries.map(c =>
      <li>
        <ul>
          {Object.values(c.languages).map(l => <li>{l}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </li>
    )
  }
</ul>
```